# Android searching a string array

Tags: java, android, search

I am currently trying to search an array list and display results that matched a user's query. I keep on getting a ConcurrentModificationException and do not know how to fix it. The code in my searchable activity is as follows:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

ListView l;

String[] testArray;
List<String> testArrayList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    testArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list);
    testArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(testArray));

    l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testArrayList);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        //Log.d("Event", query);

        search(query);
    }
}

private void search(String query){

    for (String element : testArrayList) {
        if (!element.contains(query)) {
            testArrayList.remove(element);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for (String element : testArrayList) {
    if (!element.contains(query)) {
        testArrayList.remove(element);
    }
}
```

you should not remove elements while iterating collection, change it to something like this (not tested):

```
Iterator<String> iter = testArrayList.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
   if (!iter.next().contains(query)) {
        iter.remove();
}
```